# how to prove a function is not continuous in a $(-\infty,+\infty)?$

Tags: limits, functions

given:
$$g(x) = \frac{x-4x^3+1}{x^3-5+2x^2}$$

1) 
calculate the limit of
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{ 10g(x)^2- 3g(x)}{6-g(x)}$$

I think thats equal to 17.2 but im probably mistaken.

2) prove that $g(x)$ is NOT continuous in the section $(-\infty, \infty)$

thats a harder one for me...

thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you prove that at some point the denominator vanishes, but numerator does not?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the function is never discontinuous, it is simply undefined at some points.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
For part 1), you should expand the expression and compare the terms of highest degree.

For part 2), note that the denominator cannot be $0$! If it has an zero and cannot be cancelled out with the numerator, then you get a discontinuity.

A polynomial of degree $3$ must have a real root.

Comment: I'm having problems with part 2, i need to find g(x)=6 in order to find the point which will give me a denominator of 0.      how to solve such a big polynomial fraction I can't remember

Comment: @RYU $g(x)-6$ is the denominator in part $1$, which has nothing to do with part $2$. You need to prove that $x^3-5+2x^2$ has a root.

Comment: how to do that? i tried for a while and can't remember how to do that... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach for part 1 is to first calculate the limit of $g(x)$ as $x \to \infty$, which is $-4$ by comparing the leading coefficients. Then, by certain limit rules, the limit that you are trying to calculate can be obtained by simply replacing $g(x)$ with $-4$ as such:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{10g(x)^2 - 3g(x)}{6 - g(x)} = \frac{10(-4)^2 - 3(-4)}{6 - (-4)} = 17.2$$